# Java Variable initialized through ANT is not reflected while invoking test using testNG

Tags: java, ant, testng

I am working on testNG and ANT based framework.

Inside build.xml, we have:

```
            <delete dir="${test.output}${file.separator}tenantV3Management-cli"/>
            <testng classpathref="jars.classpath"
                    outputdir ="${test.output}${file.separator}tenantV3Management-cli"
                    haltOnfailure="false"
                    listeners="com.oracle.common.CustomReporter"
                    testnames="tenantV3Management-cli">
                <classpath location="${target.test.classes.dir}"/>
                <classpath refid="jars.classpath" />
                <sysproperty key="tempFileLoc" value="${code.build.tempfiles}${file.separator}"/>
                <xmlfileset dir="${basedir}" includes="config${file.separator}settingsCLI.xml"/>
            </testng>
</target>
```

Inside Constants.java, I have used :

`public static boolean isSim3_1Tests=false;`

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
                String testProp = "SIMV3.1";
                Properties sysProps = System.getProperties();
                testProp=sysProps.getProperty(testProp);
                if (testProp.equals(false)) {
                         isSim3_1Tests = false;
                } else {
                        isSim3_1Tests = true;
                }

        }
```

And my TestClass.java is extending Constants.java
My test case goes like this:

```
    @Test(groups = {"tenantV3ManagementTest"}, timeOut = 100000)
    public void testUpgradeTenant() throws IDMMultiTenancyException {
         System.out.println("isSim3_1Tests="+Constants.isSim3_1Tests);
          ...
    }
```

Here when the test case is invoked, isSim3_1Tests is coming out to be false whereas I am setting it to true in the main() of its super class Constants.java

Kindly suggest, why is this happening and how to correct this issue?
I am stuck on it and any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You never actually look up any property out of `sysProps`. You just compare the string *key* (which should be declared as a constant) to `Boolean.FALSE`, which will always be false.

**Edit:** You're now looking up out of the `Properties` object, but the result is a `String`, which can never equal `Boolean.FALSE`. Instead of the redundant (and erroneous) construct you have, use something like `BooleanUtils` from commons-lang:

```
Constants.isSim3_1Tests = BooleanUtils.toBoolean(testProp); // and "Constants" is a bad name
```

Comment: I am looking up a property from sysProps only..There was one typo, I have edited the original question with the correction